# Reducing response latency for public API hosted behind CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cloudfront, latency

I am using a public API hosted behind CloudFront. I want to get the least possible latency.

I have done the following things so far:

1. Hosted my code on EC2 in the same region as the API origin server. (I have a clue as to which region the origin server could be hosted in based on ping times)
2. Tried pinging the API domain name from various availability zones within that region and identified the zone with least ping time.

However during my testing, I came across instances where ping time from my desktop was smaller than the ping time from my EC2 instance. So I had a look at what the CNAME & IP, the original API domain name was getting resolved to in each case. I found them to be different.

Is there something I can do to ensure that DNS resolution of CloudFront leads me to the lowest latency link.

I can use the CNAME or IP that I found to be the fastest during my testing. But that CNAME/IP may change so that's not a proper solution.

I think the answer could lie in a smart DNS client which pings all the servers in DNS file periodically and resolves DNS requests to the the fastest IP. However I don't know if any such client exists and how to use it if it does.

I would like to hear your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something I can do to ensure that DNS resolution of CloudFront leads me to the lowest latency link.

If you have your own domain name, you could try using Route53's [latency record](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-latency) or [Geoproximity routing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-geoproximity)